# Use sleep function but allow for input to end macro?

Tags: excel, vba, sleep, interrupt

i have a macro that loops and uses the sleep function for a random interval between 5 seconds and 120 seconds after each loop. When the macro goes to sleep after carrying operations i am unable to end the macro without resorting to using control break where control break seems to work intermittently. So my question is this. How would i go about putting the macro to sleep for any amount of time but to also be able to terminate the macro at any time during sleep without control break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach to pausing in line would be to use `Application.OnTime` ...

```
Public Sub PauseInBackground()
    Dim lngSeconds As Long, strNextTime As String
    
    Randomize (Second(Time))
    lngSeconds = Rnd() * 120
    
    strNextTime = Format(DateAdd("s", lngSeconds, DateValue("01/01/1800")), "hh:mm:ss")

    Debug.Print "Next Time = " & strNextTime
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(strNextTime), "RoutineToRun"
End Sub

Public Sub RoutineToRun()
    Debug.Print "Now = " & Now()
    
    ' Your code/logic
    
    PauseInBackground
End Sub
```

... it won't pause the macro in place.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Comment: No worries!  Feel free to flag it as the answer then.  Also, I just cleaned up the setting of the `strNextTime` variable.  It's much better now.

Comment: Now its even better. But i have one more question. How do i stop the on time event. Im trying to stop it now and even control break is not working for me. Can it be done with another Macro that i can execute?

Comment: Yep, run another routine from a button or whatever that sets a global Boolean variable (maybe call it “STOP_TIMER” or something) and then in the “RoutineToRun” sub (as per my example) put the first line in the code block to be … If STOP_TIMER Then Exit Sub … make sense? It then won’t run again.

Comment: Or … if you look at the parameters, to Application.OnTime, you can cancel existing schedules by setting the last parameter to false.